# Vue.js error when importing external .scss file

Tags: sass, vuejs2, vue-loader

I'm importing .scss file in a vue component, but receiving this odd error.
'file not found'
I'm sure the path of file is correct and don't know why getting this error?

Code:

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
  @import './style.scss';
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved but don't know why!

When I removing 'scoped' tag, everything is back to normal. I find out a little bit about global and local styles in vue-loader in this: 
https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html

But don't know why this happening.
Appreciate if some one can explain.

```
<style lang="scss">
  @import './style.scss';
</style>
```

Comment: I would assume that an import cannot be scoped. Scoped styles are unique to the component but an imported stylesheet could be used anywhere. Note that CSS imports don't 'include' the contents like a server side script might; it's more like a link to an external file rather than 'bring the external file contents here'